# ssh jump host connection with target machine authentication via a private key

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to connect to a target machine via ssh jump host. Authentication to target machine is done via a private key on jump host. A manual way will be made of 2 steps:

```
ssh me@jumphost.com
ssh -i priv.key target@targethosst.com
```

When I try to reach the same result via *-J*:

```
ssh -J me@jumphost.com -i priv.key target@targethosst.com
```

I get:

> Warning: Identity file os.key not accessible: No such file or directory.

One solution that I found is

```
ssh -t me@jumphost.com 'ssh -i priv.key target@targethosst.com'
```

Is there a way to reach the same result with -J command and hinting to look for the private key in the jump host, not local machine?

Comment: That's not possible. Setting up a jump host configures port forwarding via the jump host, but doesn't actually run an `ssh` command on the jump host.

Comment: I see. Then I will stick with `-t` option. Thanks!